# Free positioning of buttons relative and over responsive image

Tags: bootstrap-4

Aim is to create a visual that illustrates a learning topic. Specific areas shall be clickable to be able to call a modal containing learning content. My problem is, that I'm not able to position the buttons over the image so that their position remain being relativ to the area in the image where they belong to when resizing due to changes window size or different device. 
Maybe I'm completely wrong in thinking and try to square the circle. If, just let me know ;-)

I tried using a code snipplet I found here. Vertical positioning is possible. Horizontal positioning not.

```css
.img-wrapper {
  position: relative;
 }

.img-responsive {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.img-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left:0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.img-overlay:before {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  height: 25%;

}
```

```html
     <head>
            <title>IoW</title>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
         
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.bootstrap.min.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom_iow.css">
         
            <script src="script/jquery.min.js"></script>
        
            <script src="script/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <script src="script/adscript.js"></script>
        
        </head>
        
        <body style="background-color:#009BA5;">
            <div class="img-wrapper">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-640-480-6.jpg">
                <div class="img-overlay">
                    <button href="#modOpt" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-md btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Golden Circle</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal fade" id="modOpt" role="dialog">
                <!-- Some modal code -->
            </div>
        </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `position:absolute` combined with `top:50%`, `left:50%` and `transform(-50%, -50%)` on your `.img-overlay` to achieve that behaviour.

While `top` and `left` 50% offset the `.img-overlay` 50% of the parents height/width the `transform` pulls it back into the other direction by 50% of the `img-overlay` own size.

```css
.img-wrapper {
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
}
.img-wrapper img {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.img-overlay {
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display:block;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-wrapper">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/500x500" alt=""/>
  <a href="#" class="img-overlay">Lorem</a>
</div>

<div class="img-wrapper">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/800x450" alt=""/>
  <a href="#" class="img-overlay">Lorem</a>
</div>

<div class="img-wrapper">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/1920x1080" alt=""/>
  <a href="#" class="img-overlay">Lorem</a>
</div>
```

Comment: This unfortunately led to the picture being scaled to squared dimension. And the button has been positioned again centered. The picture shall cover the whole available space by keeping it's dimensions and the button shall be positioned whereever needed but nonetheless keeping its position relative to the image whilsts scaling.

Comment: @Chris i updated the snippet so you can see its not fixed to 500x500. I just had it fixed to 500x500 so the snippet doesnt explode on a big screen. I removed that, so the image does now take full space and the link keeps its position relative to the image (always centered). You can modify that by the "top" and "left" values to whatever you need it to be.

Comment: sorry, was a few days off and offline. Thats why I respond so late. Nearly there now. Unfortunately the image doesn't scale to the full size. I changed .img-wrapper img to height:auto which had no effect. Do you have an idea how to solve?

Comment: I deleted /*display:inline-block;*/. The image scales to fit the window. But now it is slightly too high. I guess this is because the dimensions doesn't fit, right?

Comment: Images are inline Elements by default. To make them behave like a block you have to set it to `display:block` or `display:inline-block`. The block behaviour is needed so the image is pushing the box to its own height and width and the centering works then.